# A question on Ampere Circuital Law

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

If we consider an infinitely long wire carrying current and apply the law by considering a circular loop at a distance $r$ we get,
$$B=\frac{\mu i}{2r\pi}$$

All good.

But If I apply the same law for a piece of wire (not infinitely long), I get the same result. Which is not correct. My question is why does this happen? Why doesn't ACL work  for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the wire is not infinitely long you must have some mechanism for passing a current through it.
For example is you choose a length of straight wire $AB$ you need connecting wires to it and a voltage/current source to allow a current to pass through the wire $AB$.

That connecting wire will produce a magnetic field which you probably not have included in your Ampere's law calculation?

If you try and be clever and arrange that there are charges at each end of the wire to provide the electric current then you have to include the $\frac {d\,\,}{d t}\int\vec E\cdot d\vec A$ term as the electric field is changing.

Comment: In other words:  an isolated segment of current is non-physical.  What should one expect applying the laws of physics to a non-physical situation?  Nothing reliable.